# Is testing features enough?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

The title says it all, if I test using capybara :

```
visit this page
expect this content
```

and do this for every single feature(e.g signin, signup, search, clicking all the links and buttons, etc), would that be enough? Why would I need to test controllers and models? If features are working as expected, doesn't that mean everything is working in harmony?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That technique is called black *box testing* also know as *functional testing*. If you are testing as if you are a user of the application it is considered *black box*. If you are testing it from within it is considered *glass box testing*.

[image]

The question of whether or not is it enough is a matter of personal opinion. My opinion is if it is thorough enough then yes it could be enough.

> Some of the advantages of black-box testing include:

- You have a good chance of writing tests that weren’t imagined by the programmer.
- The environment the program is running is also tested
- The invested effort can be used multiple times

> Some advantages of glass-box testing include:

- It forces you to reason carefully about implementation.
- Spots the Dead Code or other issues with respect to best programming practices.
- Reveals errors in hidden code.